# how to create a directory in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to download images and save it to storage in a unique directory name using dio and path_provider.but i have an error:

```
I/flutter (15977): FileSystemException: Cannot open file, 
path = '/data/user/0/com.manga.indonesia.manga.suka/app_flutter/sensei-wa-koi-o-oshie-rarenai-chapter-7-bahasa-indonesia/0.jpg'
```

How can i make this `sensei-wa-koi-o-oshie-rarenai-chapter-7-bahasa-indonesia` directory?

My code :

```dart
downloadChapter(chapter) async {
    Response res;
    Dio dio = new Dio();
    var dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    try {
      res = await dio
          .get('http://0.0.0.0:8080/api/MangaSuka/kchapters/' + chapter);

      var contentChapter = res.data['content'].where((a) {
        return a != null;
      }).toList();
      for (var i = 0; i < contentChapter.length; i++) {
        await dio.download(contentChapter[i], "${dir.path}/${chapter}/$i.jpg",
            onProgress: (rec, total) {
          print("Rec: $rec , Total: $total");
        });
      };
      return print(contentChapter);
    } catch (e) {
      return print(e);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It is well explained in [flutter documentation](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-io/Directory-class.html):

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  new Directory('sensei-wa-koi-o-oshie-rarenai-chapter-7-bahasa-indonesia').create()
    // The created directory is returned as a Future.
    .then((Directory directory) {
      print(directory.path);
  });
}
```

However, in many situations, like creating one directory, perhaps the async (default) version of Directory.create will not be time saving and could perhaps result in race condition. In that case, using the sync version of the command would be more appropriate:

```
new Directory('sensei-wa-koi-o-oshie-rarenai-chapter-7-bahasa-indonesia').createSync()
// ... following sequential code
```

Of note, many dart::io methods have *Sync versions.

Answer (score 5):

### Create several directories using `recursive: true`

```
import 'dart:io';
...

var directory = await Directory('dir/subdir').create(recursive: true);
```

Check out the [official information](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/Directory-class.html).

Answer (score 3):

**01. Step**
Get a specific directory path from OS using *path_provider* package

Eg:

```
Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();  
String tempPath = tempDir.path;

Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();  
String appDocPath = appDocDir.path;
```

**02.Step**
Make your custom directory relative to the above os directory path

Eg:

```
String myDirectoryName = "sensei-wa-koi-o-oshie-rarenai-chapter-7-bahasa-indonesia";  
String relativePath = "$appDocPath/$myDirectoryName";
```

**03.Step**
Create Directory class instance and call `create()` method

```
Directory myNewDir = await Directory('$relativePath').create(recursive: true);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import 'package:path_provider_ex/path_provider_ex.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:simple_permissions/simple_permissions.dart';
//packages
//  simple_permissions: ^0.1.9
//  path_provider_ex:
//Android mainfest 
//  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 //   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
main(){
  List<StorageInfo> _storageInfo = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initPlatformState();
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      createFolder();
    });
  }
  createFolder() async {
    PermissionStatus permissionResult =
        await SimplePermissions.requestPermission(
            Permission.WriteExternalStorage);
    if (permissionResult == PermissionStatus.authorized) {
    //   Directory _appFile = Directory(_storageInfo[0].rootDir + '/MyTestFOlder');
    // _appFile.create();
     new Directory(_storageInfo[0].rootDir + '/MyCreatedFolder').create()
    // The created directory is returned as a Future.
    .then((Directory directory) {
      print(directory.path);
  });
      // File ourTempFile = File(_appFile.path);
      // print(ourTempFile.path);
     // ourTempFile.create();
      // code of read or write file in external storage (SD card)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: `_storageInfo` is never initialized